# SQL Server 2012: JOIN 3 tables for a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables: TABLEA (ID INT, name VARCHAR(2))

```
ID  Name 
01  A4
01  SH
01  9K
02  M1
02  L4
03  2G
03  99
```

TableB(Name VARCHAR(2))

```
Name 
5G
U8
02
45
23
J7
99
9F
A4
H2....
```

TableC(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(2)) (prepopulated with ID from tableA) (same number of records as A)

```
ID  Name 
01  NULL
01  NULL
01  NULL
02  NULL
02  NULL
03  NULL
03  NULL
```

I want to populate C.Name from B.Name so that for same ID (say 1), it should have different values than A.Name . So, C.Name can not have (A4, SH, 9K) for ID = 1 because they already exist in A.name. 
Also, A.name may or maynot exist in B.name.

Problem here is that I dont have additional columns in tableB. Do I need more columns to JOIN my tables? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: **Please:** always put the **concrete database system** and its version (like: `sql-server-2012`) you're using as a tag when asking a question - thanks!

Comment: Sure. I will keep it in mind. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a rather inefficient, nested query structure in an `update` clause.

In SQL Server syntax:

```
update tableC
    set Name = (select top 1 b.name
                from TableB b 
                where b.name not in (select name from TableA a where a.id = TableC.id)
                order by NEWID()
               )
```

The inner most `select` from TableA gets all the names from the same id.  The `where` clause chooses names that are *not* in this list.  The `order by () limit 1` randomly selects one of the names.

Here is an example of the code that works, according to my understanding of the problem:

```
declare @tableA table (id int, name varchar(2));
declare @tableB table (name varchar(2));
declare @tableC table (id int, name varchar(2))

insert into @tableA(id, name)
    select 01, 'A4' union all
    select 01, 'SH' union all
    select 01, '9K' union all
    select 02, 'M1' union all
    select 02, 'L4' union all
    select 03, '2G' union all
    select 03, '99';

insert into @tableB(name)
    select '5G' union all
    select 'U8' union all
    select '02' union all
    select '45' union all
    select '23' union all
    select 'J7' union all
    select '99' union all
    select '9F' union all
    select 'A4' union all
    select 'H2';


insert into @tableC(id)
    select 01 union all
    select 01 union all
    select 01 union all
    select 02 union all
    select 02 union all
    select 03 union all
    select 03;

/*    
select * from @tableA;
select * from @tableB;
select * from @tableC;
 */

update c
    set Name = (select top 1 b.name
                from @TableB b 
                where b.name not in (select name from @TableA a where a.id = c.id)
                order by NEWID()
               )
from @tableC c

select *
from @tableC
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The multi-part identifier "TableC.id" could not be bound.

Comment: The updated query is picking up one name for each customer. may be I should have made this clear (my bad) that every updated row should pick up name randomly. for example, C.ID = 1 should get C.Names x, y, z where x y z do not exist in A.names but do exist in B.Name.    I know its confusing and I appreciate all your help :)

Comment: This is accurate but with a little specification what I want each C.name to be populated as DISTINCT for each ID.   C.Name can not have same Value for the same ID.  We can however have same C.name values for different IDs.

Comment: I accepted the answer but realized that I still have duplicate data problem .

Comment: @BhupinderSingh . . . The original question was about no duplicates from TableC to TableA, not within TableA.  My answer is getting a bit long.  Could you post another question (reference this one) and add the additional constraint that names don't get reused for table C?

Comment: Posted as : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513371/updating-a-column-based-on-3-tables-and-2-rules