# Updating a column based on 3 tables and 2 rules

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three tables as follows:

```
declare @tableA table (id int, name varchar(2));
declare @tableB table (name varchar(2));
declare @tableC table (id int, name varchar(2))
insert into @tableA(id, name)
    select 01, 'A4' union all
    select 01, 'SH' union all
    select 01, '9K' union all
    select 02, 'M1' union all
    select 02, 'L4' union all
    select 03, '2G' union all
    select 03, '99';

insert into @tableB(name)
    select '5G' union all
    select 'U8' union all
    select '02' union all
    select '45' union all
    select '23' union all
    select 'J7' union all
    select '99' union all
    select '9F' union all
    select 'A4' union all
    select 'H2';
insert into @tableC(id)
    select 01 union all
    select 01 union all
    select 01 union all
    select 02 union all
    select 02 union all
    select 03 union all
    select 03;
```

Basically, @TableC.ID is populated from @TableA.ID (same rows)

Now, I have to populate @tableC.Name considering the following rules:

1. it should get the values from @TableB.name , provided that the same @TableA.name should not exists for same ID in @TableA. So for ID = 1, @TableC.name should be any values but A4, SH, 9K.
2. @tableC.Name should be DISTINCT for each @TableC.ID. So @TableC.Name should not have two same values for same ID but it could have same @TableC.name for different IDs.

The query I am using to solve rule#1 is : (please edit it to apply rule #2)

```
update c
    set Name = (select top 1 b.name
                from @TableB b 
                where b.name not in (select name from @TableA a where a.id = c.id)

     order by NEWID()
               )
from @tableC c
select *
from @tableC
```

[SQL Server 2012: JOIN 3 tables for a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490625/sql-server-2012-join-3-tables-for-a-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Clean up @tableC before executing the code above:

```
declare @tableD table (id int, name varchar(2))

insert into @tableD
select distinct * from @tableC

delete from @tableC

insert into @tableC
select * from @tableD

update c
    set Name = (select top 1 b.name
                from @TableB b 
                where b.name not in (select name from @TableA a where a.id = c.id)

     order by NEWID()
               )
from @tableC c
select *
from @tableC
```

There may be a more graceful way of doing this, but this is a quick way if its not a lot of rows in @tableC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the randomness is a requirement. I've gone for a non-randomized solution:

```
; with IDs as (
    select distinct id from @tableA
), AllPossible as (
    select i.id,b.name from IDs i cross join @tableB b
), RemoveExisting as (
    select ap.id,ap.name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ap.id ORDER BY ap.name) rn
    from AllPossible ap left join @tableA a on ap.id = a.id and ap.name=  a.name
    where a.id is null
), COrdered as (
    select id,name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) rn
    from @tableC
)
update c
    set name = re.name
from
    Cordered c
        inner join
    RemoveExisting re
        on
            c.id = re.id and
            c.rn = re.rn
```

Hopefully, the names of the CTEs gives a clue about how I thought about the problem.

If randomness is a requirement, then it should be introduced somewhere close to the first `ROW_NUMBER()` expression (in the `ORDER BY` clause).